# How can I remove elements that have a name begining with undescore using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<form id="myForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="_myCheckbox01" value="on">
 <input name="myCheckbox01" type="checkbox" value="true">
</div>
```

and the pseudo javascript :

```
   var myNewForm = $("#myForm").remove("type hidden and name begins with _");
```

What is the correct way to do this ? I want to keep them in the original dom and create a new object, which is the same except without the underscored named elements.

(The reason I am doing this is because spring-mvc form tag creates the hidden inputs, however I am serializing the form, and posting as json - which is then converted to a java object, the pojo has no fields begining undescore so it causes problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the *starts with* CSS attribute [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

```
$('input[name^="_"]').remove();
```

will remove the elements from the DOM.

**Edit**

You could clone `<input>` starting with an underscore, remove the underscore from the clone and append it to the DOM.

```
var hidden = $('#myForm input[name^="_"]');
var clone = hidden.clone();
clone.attr('name', clone.attr('name').substring(1));
hidden.after(clone);
```

Will need an edit to work with multiple `_` starting elements.

**Edit 2** For multiple `<input>`s

```
$('#myForm input[name^="_"]').each(function() {
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    clone.attr('name', clone.attr('name').substring(1));
    $(this).after(clone);
});
```

Comment: I want to keep them in the original dom and create a new object, which is the same except without the underscored named elements

Answer (score 1):

Well you would use a  CSS Selector like below and then executing the removeNode operation,

```
$("*[name^=_]").remove();
```

Deconstructing above:

`$("*")` would yield you all the elements in the Dom,

`$("*[name]")` would yield you all the elements in the Dom with the `name` attribute

`$("*[name^=_]")` would yield all elements with `_` as starting name attribute.

now start removing them

```
$("*[id^=_]").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myNewForm = $("#myForm").filter(':not(input[name^="_"]');
```

And I also use the [serializeObject()](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-serializeobject-plugin) plugin so the final code I used looks this:

```
   var myNewForm = $("#myForm").filter(':not(input[name^="_"]').serializeObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

To select hidden fields whose name begins with `_`, you can use something like this:

```
$('#myForm input[type="hidden"][name^="_"]').remove();
```

If you merely want to remove the `_` character from the elements' names, this should work:

```
$('#myForm input[type="hidden"][name^="_"]').prop('name', function(i, oldname) {
    return oldname.substr(1);
});
```

See:

- [attribute starts with selector `[name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [attribute equals selector `[name="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)
- [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove)